# Help me tag my question?

Tags: support, retag-request

I'm not sure what I should tag my question with, so I am hoping that I can find someone to retag it: https://superuser.com/questions/499860/sqlfiddle-where-can-i-see-the-result-of-my-query.

I also did a google search for keyword: `list of tags superuser.com`, and the top 10 didn't give me a tag list.  Not in the faq.  Can someone put a link up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the big grey (blue on the main site) button that says "Tags"?

[image: tags]

If you click on that, it goes to [the list of tags](https://superuser.com/tags).

Part of why you probably didn't see many tags relating to your question is because your question isn't really on-topic for Super User. It would likely be better suited for [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), since you're asking about how to use a website. Don't re-ask your question though, we'll migrate it for you shortly if the Web Apps mods approve.

Comment: Thank you.  Please migrate the question.